# Enable Scrolling and right click in trackpad in Kali along with keyboard backlight

Tags: kali-linux, macintosh, touchpad, keyboard-backlight

I am new to this forum and Kali as well. I have a Macbook 13 inch 2015 model, and recently I installed Kali in it. I was able to configure broadcom drivers but even after googling a lot, I don't see any progress with my touchpad.
I tried using the inbuilt utility but that dosent seem to work as well. Here is a screen shot.

[image: Mouse and Touchpad Utility]

I've also tired using `synclient -i`. But it shows `bash: synclient: Command not found`

Comment: `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`